# Regex to capture {}

Tags: regex

Hi I need to create a regular Expression that will match the following pattern:

{ any characters } in a string. Possible Examples of the string:

**Example 1:**

{123} abc {456} def {789}hg
should return 3 matches:

{123},{456} and {789}

**Example 2:**

abcd{{{r} 345 } {mmm}

should return 2 mathces {r} and {mmm}

So basically the expression should match { any chacraters any number of times that are not {} and then the closing }

So far I have come up with this but it's not working :

{*[^{]}

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: You need to escape the { and } using \  "\{123\}"

Comment: Since your second example suggests a possibility of nested and potentially unbalanced braces: i.e., `{1{2{3}2}`? A regex is not good -- use a parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the one you need:

```
{[^{}]*}
```

Comment: The curlybrackets should be escaped. like this: `\{[^{}]*\}`

Answer (score 2):

Like what ILovePaperTowels said -- you the curly brackets need to be escaped if they are treated as special by the particular regex syntax you are using.

The exact answer on how to escape the curly brackets, as well as how to properly count nested brackets (in whatever way you want them to be counted), depends on the flavour of regex.