# Capture the text inside square brackets using a regex

Tags: python, regex

I saw question here:
[Regex to capture {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520052/regex-to-capture)
which is similar to what I want, but I cannot get it to work.

My data is:

```
[Honda] Japanese manufacturer [VTEC] Name of electronic lift control
```

And I want the output to be

```
[Honda], [VTEC]
```

My expression is:

```
m = re.match('(\[[^\[\]]*\])', '[Honda] Japanese manufacturer [VTEC] Name of electronic lift control')
```

I would expect:

- `m.group(0)` to output `[Honda]`
- `m.group(1)` to output `[VTEC]`

However both output `[Honda]`. How can I access the second match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to get all the matches, though you'll get them in a list, and you don't need capture groups:

```
m = re.findall('\[[^\[\]]*\]', '[Honda] Japanese manufacturer [VTEC] Name of electronic lift control')
```

Gives `['[Honda]', '[VTEC]']` so you can get each with:

```
print(m[0])
# => [Honda]

print(m[1])
# => [VTEC]
```

Answer (score 4):

You only have *one group* in your expression, so you can only ever get that one group. Group 1 is the capturing group, group 0 is the *whole matched text*; in your expression they are one and the same. Had you omitted the `(...)` parentheses, you'd only have a group 0.

If you wanted to get *all matches*, use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall). This returns a list of matching groups (or group 0, if there are no capturing groups in your expression):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\[[^\[\]]*\]', '[Honda] Japanese manufacturer [VTEC] Name of electronic lift control')
['[Honda]', '[VTEC]']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering other than re:

```
s="[Honda] Japanese manufacturer [VTEC] Name of electronic lift control"
result = []
tempStr = ""
flag = False
for i in s:
    if i == '[':
        flag = True
    elif i == ']':
        flag = False
    elif flag:
        tempStr = tempStr + i
    elif tempStr != "":
        result.append(tempStr)
        tempStr = ""

print result
```

Output:

```
['Honda', 'VTEC']
```